# Optimized away STL container's size

Tags: c++, visual-studio

While debugging an issue, I added some [tracepoints](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/using-tracepoints?view=vs-2022) printing the `size()` of an `std::queue` as

```
The size of the queue is {mQueue.size()}
```

but I see this message in the Output window

```
The size of the queue is Function std::queue<Foo>::size has no address, possibly due to compiler optimizations.
```

If I break into the code at that point, I do see the `size`

```
mQueue
    c: { size=0 }
    [Raw View]: {c={ size=0 } }
```

But again if I try `mQueue.size()` I see the same log

```
Function std::queue<Foo>::size has no address, possibly due to compiler optimizations.
```

Is there a way to get at the `size()` in the tracepoint rather than resorting to code changes to store the size in some variable and possibly printing that? I've tried wrapping the function where I've added the trace point within `#pragma optimize( "", off )` but to no avail. Also I want to avoid changing the Linker option to `/DEBUG:FULL` if possible.

Answer (score 1):

The compiler never has a need to generate code for `std::queue<Foo>::size()`, so it doesn't bother; so at runtime, the debugger doesn't have it to call.

One solution would be to explicitly instantiate the function, with something like `template std::queue<int>::size_type std::queue<int>::size()` in a source file. But that would require you to get the declaration exactly right, which would be quite a pain and would likely make the code compiler-specific and even standard-library-implementation-version-specific.

The other option is to just have a call to the appropriately typed `size()` somewhere in your code. Even in code that's never called.

Example:

```cpp
#include <queue>

void thisIsNeverCalled()
{
    std::queue<int> q;
    (void)q.size(); // If this line is present, the below tracepoint works
}

int main()
{
    std::queue<int> q;

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        q.push(i); // can trace q.size() here if the above line is present
    }
}
```

(The `(void)` is just there to quash compiler warnings from the `[[nodiscard]]` attribute.)

Note that this approach is less likely to work with optimizations enabled. To mitigate that, surround `thisIsNeverCalled` with `#pragma optimize`, and potentially force the linker to include it with a [suitable `#pragma comment`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/preprocessor/comment-c-cpp?view=msvc-170#linker).